# Artikel oder nicht - Glück währt nicht lange

Tags: sentence-structure, article, nominative

Sagt man `Glück währt nicht lange` oder `das Glück währt nicht lange`?

Mit oder ohne Artikel, oder kann man beides sagen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beides ist korrekt, beides kann man sagen - aber die Aussage ist leicht verschieden:

> Glück währt nicht lange

Das ist eine Aussage über Glück im Allgemeinen.

> Das Glück währt nicht lange

Das ist eine Aussage über ein spezielles Glück / einen speziellen glücklichen Umstand - ersichtlich an der Verwendung des bestimmten Artikels. Der Bezug ergibt sich aus dem Kontext - und dieser Kontext sollte gegeben werden, um die Frage nach "welches Glück?" zu beantworten.

Answer (score 2):

Man kann beides sagen, und die Bedeutung ist auch nahezu gleich.

Bei

> Glück währt nicht lange.

wird "Glück" eher als abstraktes Konzept verstanden, das nicht zählbar und nicht näher bestimmbar ist. Der Satz erinnert an ein Sprichwort oder eine Bauernregel.

Bei

> Das Glück währt nicht lange.

hat "das Glück" einen leicht demonstrativen Unterton. Wir reden hier möglicherweise von "diesem Glück", im Gegensatz zu einem "anderen Glück". Vielleicht wurde das spezielle Glück, das jemand hatte, vorher beschrieben:

> Von Montag bis Donnerstag hatte er jeden Morgen den Bus zur Arbeit noch erwischt. Aber das Glück währte nicht lange: Am Freitag fuhr ihm der Bus wieder vor der Nase weg.

Dieser Unterschied ist allerdings, wie gesagt, sehr klein und wird im Alltag nicht immer beachtet. In einigen Fällen wird der Sprechende vermutlich sogar einfach die Variante wählen, die rhythmisch besser passt.